# VBA PowerPoint set variable to nothing

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint

I have a question regarding the following code. The code now works, but did not until I set the Variables to nothing (see the part with the *** in the code). I got all kinds of error-messages (e.g. "462 The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable")

My question is: Why do I have to Set those Variables to nothing? I guess it has something to do with the fact that I use a loop right?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Saveas_PDF() 
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim prs As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim Sl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sh As Variant
Dim company As String
Set Dropdown.ws_company = Tabelle2
company = Dropdown.ws_company.Range("C2").Value

Dim strPOTX As String
Dim strPfad As String
Dim pptApp As Object

Call filepicker

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Dropdown.ws_company.Range(Dropdown.ws_company.Cells(5, 3), 
Dropdown.ws_company.Cells(Rows.Count, 
3).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 Dropdown.ws_company.Range("C2") = Cell

 Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

 Dim pptVorlage As String
 pptVorlage = myfilename


 Set PP = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptVorlage)



 PP.UpdateLinks 'Datei --> Informationen --> Verknüpfungen --> Automatisch 
 aktualisieren Haken setzen

 Dim newpath As String
 newpath = Replace(myfilename, "AXO", "" & Cell & " AXO")

 Dim newpathpdf As String
 newpathpdf = Replace(newpath, "pptx", "pdf")


 PP.ExportAsFixedFormat "" & newpathpdf & "", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, 
 ppFixedFormatIntentPrint


 pptApp.Visible = True

 Debug.Print (PP.Name)
 AppActivate (PP.Name)

 PP.Close

***Set pptApp = Nothing
Set PP = Nothing***

Next

Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
If IsAppRunning("PowerPoint.Application") Then
  If pptApp.Windows.Count = 0 Then

    pptApp.Quit
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When posting code for comments it's always useful to *use indenting* so it's easier to follow what's going on.  Not using indenting is a little like writing without punctuation or paragraphs.

Comment: You don't need to create a new PPT application each time through the loop - create an instance before entering the loop and then quit that instance after the loop is done.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your reply. I used some indenting to make the code easier to read

Comment: Creating an instance sounds good, but I have no idea how to do it. Can you give me a hint? Also is creating a new PPT application the problem? (Just trying to understand the logic behind the error)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are calling  the constructor "New" inside de loop in the line:  Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

Move the line "Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application" before de foreach and try it.

Comment: hehe, you can mark de answer as useful, Thank you too! :)

Comment: I did :) but i dont think its shows cause I am a new member